# Merge two text files by upserting records (update existing ones, insert new ones)

Tags: shell, unix, awk, merge, uniq

I am looking for a UNIX shell solution to perform the equivalent of a SQL `MERGE` (or `UPSERT`) between two text files, where some fields are key fields, and other fields can be updated/overwritten.

**Input data**

This is my original data:

```
AA;123;2016-01-31;1;456.53
AA;123;2016-02-01;1;75.24
AB;123;2000-08-08;1;756.1
AB;456;2016-07-07;2;8.24
CC;123;2007-07-21;15;10.34
CC;456;2009-09-09;9;943.65
CC;789;2005-04-23;1;1345.6
```

where the first three fields (*Product*, *Customer* and *Date*) are key fields, and the last two fields (*Quantity* and *Amount*) can be updated.

This is my second file which only contains new and updated data:

```
AA;123;2016-01-31;7;983.63
AA;123;2016-08-24;17;1687.73
CC;456;2009-09-09;11;2161.65
DD;91;2016-08-03;5;98.48
```

Both files have been sorted with:

```
sort -t';' -k1 -k2 -k3
```

The first and the third records should overwrite existing lines (updating *Quantity* and *Amount*), whereas the second and the third records should be inserted as new lines.

**Desired output**

```
AA;123;2016-01-31;7;983.63
AA;123;2016-08-24;17;1687.73
AA;123;2016-02-01;1;75.24
AB;123;2000-08-08;1;756.1
AB;456;2016-07-07;2;8.24
CC;123;2007-07-21;15;10.34
CC;456;2009-09-09;11;2161.65
CC;789;2005-04-23;1;1345.6
DD;91;2016-08-03;5;98.48
```

I am looking for some quick solution using `sort`, `uniq` or `awk` and `perl`.

Comment: And then I found [`awk '!a[$0]++'`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159695/how-does-awk-a0-work) two minutes after posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to overwrite the lines in file1 when the index on 1st, 2nd, 3rd fields matches in the file2. That is, the file2 has "preference" over file1, so a line in file1 is just printed if it does not have its correspondence in file2.

If so, what about printing all two files, starting by file2, and skipping those lines that are repeated file1-file2-file3-wise? Then, pipe to sort for a sorted output:

```
$ awk -F";" '!seen[$1, $2, $3]++' f2 f1 | sort
AA;123;2016-01-31;7;983.63
AA;123;2016-02-01;1;75.24
AA;123;2016-08-24;17;1687.73
AB;123;2000-08-08;1;756.1
AB;456;2016-07-07;2;8.24
CC;123;2007-07-21;15;10.34
CC;456;2009-09-09;11;2161.65
CC;789;2005-04-23;1;1345.6
DD;91;2016-08-03;5;98.48
```

Comment: @EdMorton in general, when should we avoid commas to create indexes? Just when we have lines like `1 23` that can also be `12 3`? Isn't it safe to always use `FS` to prevent it?

Comment: The `12 3` vs `1 23` problem occurs when you put nothing between your subscripts so they both concatenate to `123`. Using `,` or `FS` solves that problem. You should use `FS` (or `OFS` if appropriate) when you are going to print the array indices and/or you have multiple places you reference the index (e.g. `{key=$1 FS $2} seen[key]++{map[key]=$NF; ...} END{for (i in map) print i, map[i]}`), otherwise you should use `,` for conciseness.

Comment: @EdMorton great help, as always!

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F\; '{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3]= $4 FS $5} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"; for (i in a) print i FS a[i]}' file1 file2
AA;123;2016-01-31;7;983.63
AA;123;2016-02-01;1;75.24
AA;123;2016-08-24;17;1687.73
AB;123;2000-08-08;1;756.1
AB;456;2016-07-07;2;8.24
CC;123;2007-07-21;15;10.34
CC;456;2009-09-09;11;2161.65
CC;789;2005-04-23;1;1345.6
DD;91;2016-08-03;5;98.48
```

Explained:

```
{
    a[$1 FS $2 FS $3] = $4 FS $5    # write records overwriting where needed
} 
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" # for sort order
    for (i in a)                         # output indexed records
        print i FS a[i]
}
```

Comment: I was about to say that there was a FS too many... and you just removed it. Good one! We both have the same output and I also like the fact that you provide a nice explanation, well done!

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it in my `test.awk` and command line but forgot the posted version... TGIF.

Comment: Your NR==FNR and other blocks are identical so you don't need 2 separate blocks. Just get rid of the `NR==FNR{...}` block and what you're left with will work just fine for both files.

Comment: Lol. I really need to start proof-reading these before posting.